In EF Core is it possible to map a `System.Version` column keeping the type's unique sorting properties?
I'd like to make a Version-backed column in the database and order by it in queries, keeping the ordering consistent with what would be the result if run on the client directly. There are many entity types in the table, each has its own set of versions. Versions may have gaps, and they should only increase.
The only way to do so appears to split it into 4 separate integer columns and apply ordering on them all at the same time, but I already groan at the prospect of having to write that OrderBy() code all the time.
Is there a better way? The database is Postgres 17, if that matters, maybe I overlooked a native datatype, although being DB-agnostic is a plus.

"Better" is opinion-based. My take: store the versions in a separate table with ascending key values and add foreign keys where necessary.

This won't work with TPH. I fail to see how is it "opinion-based". Just because I used the word "better"?

Yes, because of that. And because there is very little information in your question for outsiders to judge what would work for you. It always works better to show some first efforts, making clear in which direction you heading and showing which existing code it's about. For example, only now you bring up TPH. (By the way, why wouldn't that work?)

As an option you can encode 4 integers into uuid type, which has 16 bytes. Also it is indexable.

The way I see it it works only as long as versions only increase or decrease, but with several entity types that is not going to be the case. It also assumes versions are per type, not per instance.
I didn't bring it TPH up because it is not relevant. I didn't ask to find what's best for me. I clearly laid out that I seek something that is not going to be overly verbose while letting me to sort my entities by version as it would be done in C#. If you need any details you should just ask, I'm do not have the omniscience so I may not think of something as crucial to mention it.

Again, more relevant details. Don't expect others to ask if your versions only increase or decrease and if you have several entity types. The question looked simple. If you can order by 4 integers, ordering by one integer is not essentially different, unless you want to order by different parts of the version, but you didn't mention that either (so far).

@SvyatoslavDanyliv: that's an interesting idea, which made me think more and I figured a string column with a natural sort-aware collation should also work, shouldn't it?

@ZzZombo, yes if you store 0000.0000.0001.0023 in something like this.
